# Please help identify Star Wars set - I have some very specific dark grey wings with brown paint

Tags: part-identification, set-identification, star-wars

Please see attached pic, I reckon these are part of a Star Wars ship. Can anyone help me identify the set?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These pieces are indeed Star Wars related, they are from [7957 - Sith Nightspeeder](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?S=7957-1) from 2011.

[image]